# Looking for a Scandinavian semi mythical fantasy work

Tags: story-identification

And the only clue I have is a character named Kulubak Magri (hunchback Magri? A dwarf?). And Ravens.  Read a couple of decades ago.

Anyone willing to indulge me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is pretty thin, as you realise.  Is there anything else you can recall?  Where you found it perhaps?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) and [edit] in any other details that come to mind.

Comment: What language did you read it in? Was it new when you read it? In what way was it 'semi-mythical'? I.e., did it take place in modern times with mythical elements, or was it a historic novel with mythical elements? And what sort of mythical elements? Places, creatures, magic?

Comment: How sure are you of the name Kulubak Magri? There's a [Helgi Magri](http://www.hurstwic.org/library/heroes/text/helgi.htm) appearing in Icelandic legends, although I can't find any more modern fantasy works featuring him.